# Migrating a Classic ASP application to ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net

We are in design phase of a project whose goal is replatforming an ASP classic application to ASP.Net 4.0. The system needs to be entirely web based. There are several new requirements for the new system that make this a challenging project:

1. The system needs to be database independent. It must, at version 1.0, support MS SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, Postgres and DB2.
2. The system must be able to allow easy reporting from the database by third party reporting packages.
3. The system must allow an administrative end user to create their own tables in the database through the web based interface.
4. The system must allow an administrative end user to design/configure a user interface (web based) where they can select tables and fields in the system (either our system's core tables or their own custom tables created in #3)
5. The system must allow an administrative end user to create and maintain relationships between these custom created tables, and also between these tables and our system's core tables.
6. The system must allow an administrative end user to create business rules that will enforce validation, show/hide UI elements, block certain actions based on the identity of specific users, specific user groups or privileges.

Essentially it's a system that has some core ticket tracking functionality, but allows the end user to extend the interface, business rules and the database. Is this possible to build in a .Net, Web based environment? If so, what do you think the level of effort would be to get this done? We are currently a 6 person shop, with 2.5 full time developers.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not knowledgable enough to answer your question, but if you had a better title for the question, maybe someone else might have. If any mods are seeing this, and are capable, please change the title.

Comment: Have amended to something slightly more meaningful.

Comment: Also, this should be Community Wiki.

Comment: I apologize if I've misposted or mistitled. This is my first post on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing to question is who has created these requirements? Most experienced developers will have attenmpted a generic do-everything system in the past, most often without success. This is because it is a tricky thing to get right and there are a lot of pitfalls. Does the requirement for users to create their own tables at the database level come from an experienced programmer who understands security implications and design principles or is it from a project manager who has "done a bit of programming"? Get your real world requirements sorted out first.

Instead of

> The system must allow an
>   administrative end user to **create
>   their own tables in the database**
>   through the web based interface.

Perhaps you should have the requirement

> The system must allow an
>   administrative end user to **define and 
>   store their own data** through the web
>   based interface.

This will stop you from narrowing your options. Brainstorm different implementations, create some prototypes and proff of concept designs and be prepared to throw these away.

My approach would be to completely abstract the database access to the point where you might not really be creating new Client-defined tables in the datbase itself but rather virtual tables in your data access layer. This will help make the system database agnostic.

For validation, check out [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/). It is a very easy-to use and flexible validation framework that works nicely with JQuery validation on the client side

Give yourselves about a year, and then maybe add 50% for good measure. Really, estimating this kind of project is very difficult, but we have achieved a similar scale project with a similar team in a year using best practice agile methodolgy. I am assuming that your developers are competent. This is a very challenging project as you have rightly identified.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had considered using NHibernate or Entities Framework to help abstract the database. However, I don't think either of these packages could handle on the fly additions of new types/tables. My guess is db abstraction is not the real challenge here.

Comment: NHibernate is a good option. It will save you loads of time. Consider having an Entity that is able to contain any Client Data that is saved in whatever format the client wants. If this is done right, then you don't have to worry about ANYTHING in the database. Keep your business rules in your business layer and as far from your DB as you can. Anyway. That is what I would do.

Comment: Daniel didn't say anything about any ORMs.  He was talking about designing a database layout which allows the concept of user defined data, which is well within the grasp of ORMs.

Comment: @tster: Glad you could read between the lines. That is exactly what I meant.

Comment: Tster, I would have thought that an ORM would not be a good choice here. Isn't the main purpose of an ORM to overcome the barrier between RDBMSs and an OO application tier? Given the fact that we are creating entities at runtime, I'm not sure that we would have domain objects to represent the user defined entities, nor would we have anything like a 1 to 1 mapping between these entities and tables.

Comment: If you don't allow the user to create new tables, but instead of a more flexible design with user defined data, then you can use an ORM.  But yes, if it comes down to users creating tables, then kiss the ORM goodbye.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for the suggestion of the all in one table. I think that's probably what we will end up with if we go this route. My fear though, is that this will run into performance issues. Not to mention the question of what form these entities will take through the application tier.

Comment: Exactly, @bzarah. These are all very good considerations to be thinking of right now. Essentially, you are dealing with a trade-off between being flexible at the database level or being flexible with how you work with your entities. In my experience, it is easier to make solid TESTABLE code in your business layer. Besides, one of your main requirements is to be database independent: very difficult if you want to have a flexible database.

Comment: @bzarah: email address is in my profile, for today only, if you want to take this offline.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the skill of the people doing the assignment. Give the requirements to the developers and try to get an estimate from them.

PS. please eleborate the question in the title of the question 'Can it be done' is a bit generic ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but for numbers like 3 and 5 why not use available software? Sun query tools, Ms sql management studuio, etc..

Answer (score 0):

You provided 6 questions/requirements and below is just my honest opinion.

1. Developing a system that has the ability to use a variety of DB backends is definitely possible and a nice approach.
2. Allowing read access into one of the DB backens for Reporting capabilities by Third party tools is a common scenario and possible.
3. Allowing System administrators to modify DB structure (ie, add/edit/delete tables/colums) this is a questionable practice.  Why recreate the wheel.  Each of the Database Backends that you mentioned have administration tools built to manage the modification of database structures.  More so if you plan to deploy this on the public internet then you open up the possiblility for disaster. If they are system administrators, why not just use the tools already created? Its safer, easier to develop, and in the end easier to support.
4. Allowing a enduser to configure an admin to configure the user interface by changing label names, hiding fields, requiring a field.  This is not a problems on core tables but as for user defined tables see my comments on #3.
5. Allowing admin to create and maintian relationships (ie foreign keys, primary keys, unique keys) from the web is just as dangerous and a pain in the butt as #3. Why recreate the wheel?
6. Your last question/requirement states alot.  All I can say is start with allowing the user to customize the User Interface a little bit (hide/show fields, making a field required in a form).  As for the rules engine, there are frameworks out there that handle rules/workfow. Perhaps some research on one of these frameworks would be helpful to you. Microsoft has Windows Workflow Foundation

Overall your not the first to come up with a these types of ideas.  But the overall development and maintainability of an applicaiton like this could be a nightmare.

Comment: John, thanks for the suggestion of using third party tools. I'm guessing that that may be a viable option. Many of the clients don't require anything other than the core system, while others could use a third party package to extend as needed. My boss really wants to create a system that can be changed at runtime, but it's probably more likely that we need to just do an extended consultation during the installation of the application and try and give them 95% of what they need on day one, letting the last 5% go.

Comment: Note if during the discovery stage of your new implementation, you find that you need to add a field or add a table.  You could implement these new features as core features.  By using your UI configuration hide the unnecessary features for clients that dont want or need it.  But you may find that what one client wants another wants the same thing but just does not know how to describe it.

Comment: I would suggest you don't try to give them 95% on day one. Give them 5% on day 10, the most important 5%. Then, the second most important 5% on day 20 and so on. Read up on agile. Deliver a small amount of functionality early and regularly. Because requirements change.

Answer (score -1):

First off, yes all that **can** be done, but they aren't really requirements so much as implementation details.  When you say an end use should be able to "create a new table," what you should say is "an end use should be able to define a new entity type."  It doesn't necessarily have to have it's own table.

Anyways, if you only have 2.5 developers (and I assume you are one of those), and you don't have enough experience to look at all the requirements and the current system and estimate the feasibility, then I don't think the project would be a success.

Comment: I agree that one could say "Entity". But that in itself is an implementation detail. For all I know, considering the dynamic nature of the application, it may not have an object oriented solution at all. Perhaps we will be throwing around DTOs of some kind in the middle layer. I've simply posed the actual requirement I've been given. I have been asked to create tables in the database. And have a dynamic front end.

Comment: Remember, good programmers don't take the provided requirements as gospel.  You need to work with the users to figure out what the real requirements are, and not just the dribble that the average project manager writes out.

Comment: Agreed. I'm actually pushing to limit the scope of this to some User defined fields off the existing core entities. I had hoped that everyone would comment that writing a system that can allow an end user to create their own application would require a monstrous effort. I could then use your comments to back up my position. But since you're slamming my new boss (day 2 on the job) I'll just keep this to myself. :)

Thanks for your comments tster. They are much appreciated.

Comment: @bzarah,  You are right to try and limit the scope of this since what the requirements sound like is allowing end users to program, which in the end will always be a failure.

Comment: Agreed. Building an application that allows the end users to build their own application is in fact what I'm being asked to do. There are examples of software that do this. MS Access, FileMaker Pro etc. But we are not a huge software shop, and I don't think this kind of thing is easily implemented on the web.

Comment: +1 tster. @bzarah. Show your new boss some of the out-of-the-box implementations of this like SAP and Navision. Then tell them that the hundreds of thousands of $/£ that they would spend to achieve the same for these is because it is a very complex thing to do. Is your new boss technical? Would you be able to create a system that looks like it is creating new "tables", even though it has a better design than actually creating new tables? You can make it look to the end user that they are "Creating a new table". What you store and how you store it is up to you.

Comment: My boss's technical roots are as an Oracle DBA. I think the "Creating a new table" is meant literally. Though, if the users need a simple DB interface for reporting, there are always ways of tackling that issue separately (views, replicate data to separate reporting server). I think the approach to point out how much $$$ went into similar enterprise systems might be a good one to help illustrate how difficult this task is. At the end of the day, we NEED to get off ASP/VB6 COM. I'm going to suggest we re-implement the existing system on the new platform and add the tricky stuff later.